# String variable in Helm

Tags: jenkins, groovy, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run the following groovy script in Jenkins:

```
    def test() {
    def RV1 = '\"' + "$RELEASE_VERSION" + '\"'
    echo RV1

    sh """
       helm upgrade --install -f container-root/helm/values-dev-caas.yaml --set image.registry=docker-reg --set-string image.version=""" + RV1 + """ test_app container-root/helm --namespace test --debug
    """
```

The result is in Jenkins log:

```
helm upgrade --install -f container-root/helm/values-dev-caas.yaml --set image.registry=docker-reg --set-string image.version=202305251424 test-app container-root/helm --namespace test --debug
```

which causing an error saying

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.labels of type string
```

The result of the echo RV1 is "202305251424"

In the RV1 varaible I'm trying to add " (double quotes) to my image.version, because if I had image.version="202305251424" instead of image.version=202305251424 it would work, but somehow the double quotes get disappeared when I run the pipeline.

If I'm using this:

```
def RV1 = '\'' + '\"' + "$RELEASE_VERSION" + '\"' + '\''
```

the result in the echo is '"202305251510"' and the final command look like this in Jenkis log:

```
helm upgrade --install -f container-root/helm/values-dev-caas.yaml --set image.registry=docker-reg --set-string 'image.version="202305251510"' test_app container-root/helm --namespace test --debug
```

which causing an error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on helm/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 72: did not find expected key
```

Do you have any idea how I can add double quotes in sh in groovy or how can I make Helm understand  that it is a String and not Integer?

Comment: Do you have the template code that uses `.Values.image.version`?  I think the `helm install --set-string` is right(ish) but if you dump that back out unquoted into a YAML file it will be interpreted as a number again.

Comment: Try this `--set-string 'image.version=202305251510'`

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this issue adding quotes in the deployment.yaml where the integer is used.

```
labels:
  image-version: {{ .Values.image.version | quote }}
```

Then I could use integer in the image.version:

```
helm upgrade --install -f container-root/helm/values-dev-caas.yaml --set image.registry=docker-reg --set-string image.version=202305251424 test-app container-root/helm --namespace test --debug
```